# Passing Table values to action class

Tags: java, javascript, struts

In one of my web pages I have a HTML table. This table will have 0 or more rows and each row has 3 columns.

It looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row1-Col1</td> 
        <td>Row1-Col2</td>
        <td>Row1-Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row2-Col1</td> 
        <td>Row2-Col2</td>
        <td>Row3-Col1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to transfer the values of the columns (content of td's) to Action class.

Is there a way to

1. get the number of rows in a table
2. transfer the values using javascript and how will I get them in my action class

Struts 2 btw.

Thanks

Comment: Struts 1 or 2? Value of columns - what do you mean: html values inside td tags or do you have input fields?

Comment: i am using struts 2 and i mean html values inside td tag.... i am not using input fields

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions, I guess, that you have this rows in an iterator...

So the JSP would look like that:

```
<s:form action="myAction">
<table>
    <s:iterator value="someCollection" status="stat">
        <!-- set id of column -->
        <tr id="myTd<s:property value="#stat.index" />">
            <td>some html</td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
<s:hidden name="lastIndex" />
<s:hidden name="htmlValues" />
<s:submit onclick="submitValues();">
</s:form>
```

JS file:

```
function submitValues() {
     var htmlValue;
     int i = 0;
     while(document.getElementById('myId'+i)) {
         htmlValue += document.getElementById('myId'+i).innerHTML;
         i++;
     }
     document.getElementyById('lastIndex').value = i;
     document.getElementyById('htmlValues').value = htmlValue;
}
```

Action class:

```
public MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private Integer lastIndex;
    private String htmlValues;

    public String execute() {
         //here there should be values filled
         System.out.println(getLastIndex);
    }
}
```

I did not test this, so maybe there could be mistakes, but the main idea is shown. Of course, you will get in `htmlValues` in action class in html form, but there are a lot of html parses out there.